# What is difference between elementor and elementor addons

Tags: wordpress, plugins, themes, add-on, elementor

I just want to know about complete difference between Elementor and Elementor addons.
**And please recommend me a channel where I can learn elementor addons.**
Thanx

Answer (score 2):

First, let's understand

**1. What is Elementor?**

Elementor is a page builder plugin that replaces the basic WordPress editor with a live frontend editor, so you can create complex layouts visually, and design your website live, without having to switch between the editor and the preview mode. The page builder enables you to reach a top-notch quality of design without needing to use code or CSS, and without relying on developers for help.

[image]

The user interface is extremely friendly, so it only takes a few minutes to get the hang of it. We’ve built Elementor with the latest technology, and have kept updating it steadily since our launch on June 16′, so the whole page builder is optimized and fast responding. This means, for example, that when you drag and drop widgets, it is done instantly, without any lag time at all.

**2. What is Elementor Addons?**

In simple words, it's extending the Elementor functionality.

Let's take one example:

> Elementor provides the default website element like Columns, Heading,
> Video, Button and etc. we can create our own element which we want.

The fact that Elementor is free and open source has allowed for developers to extend Elementor even further. They have also released the [Elementor API](https://developers.elementor.com/), which includes a detailed explanation on extending Elementor and creating add-ons and extensions.

For more details here I have shared the official website [link](https://elementor.com/blog/what-is-elementor-for-wordpress/).

Answer (score 0):

Elementor is the core page builder plugin that provides the foundation for creating websites, while Elementor Addons are optional plugins that extend the capabilities of Elementor by providing additional features and functionalities.